# $C([0, 1],[0, 1])$ is dense in $\Pi_{[0, 1]}[0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is the space $C([0, 1], [0, 1])$ of continuous functions $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ dense in the space $\Pi_{[0, 1]}[0, 1]$ of all such functions regarding pointwise convergence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The product space $\prod_{[0,1]}[0,1]$ has the product topology (aka the topology of pointwise convergence) and a basic non-empty set has the form $\prod_{x \in [0,1]} U_x$ where all $U_x=[0,1]$ except for a $x$ in some finite set $F \subseteq [0,1]$ when $U_x$ is some non-empty open subset of $[0,1]$. Pick $y_x \in U_x$ for those $x$ and find a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ that obeys $f(x) = y_x$ for all $x \in F$ (a piecewise linear funcntion or a polynomial can be found) and this $f$ then lies in the open set and the set $C([0,1],[0,1])$ showing the latter set is dense.